# Understand outputs for predict_proba for MultiOutputClassifier XGBoost model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost, multilabel-classification

I have a multioutputclassifier model with XGboost and scikit-learn, with 28 classes. The predict_proba returns a list of 28 arrays with the shape of 13412*28 (13412 are the number of samples in my testing dataset).

I have difficulty in interpreting these probabilities. I have a list of my classes from clf.classes_ but I am facing issues in understanding how to exactly read these probability arrays.

```py
Y_ml1.shape
```

(125157L, 28L)

```py
best_XGB = XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', colsample_bylevel=1,
       colsample_bytree=0.7, gamma=0.1, learning_rate=0.2,
       max_delta_step=0, max_depth=12, min_child_weight=3, missing=None,
       n_estimators=100, n_jobs=1, nthread=None,
       objective='multi:softprob', random_state=0, reg_alpha=0,
       reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1, seed=None, silent=True,
       subsample=1, num_class =len(list(ml.classes_)))

multi_target_classifier = MultiOutputClassifier(best_XGB, n_jobs=1)
multi_target_classifier.fit(m1, Y_ml1)
y_pred_proba = multi_target_classifier.predict_proba(test_x)
len(y_pred_proba)
```

28

```py
y_pred_proba[0].shape
```

(13412L, 28L)

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your question, but for each of the 13412 samples in the test set, you have a vector of 28 numbers which sum up to 1. The position of the bigger one should be the predicted class

Comment: Thanks Vincenzo for your reply. You are right, columns for 13412 test samples sum up to 1. But I have 28 such vectors.

`len(y_pred_proba)`    
28  

.So the thing I am not able to understand is that the first array `(y_pred_proba[0])` for class 'A' (n_samples, n_classes), is it showing the probability that the sample is class 'A' compared to all other 28 classes?

Comment: Exactely: `y_pred_proba[0][0]` is the probability that that sample belongs to class 'A'. So if you want to know which is the predicted class for that sample, you can check which one is the biggest component of that vector, in magnitute. Something along `np.argmax(y_pred_proba[0])`